# Creating Control Under Draw Tab in manifest.xml

Tags: powerpoint, office-js

Is it possible to add any control to the PowerPoint's Draw tab? Draw tab's ID is not given in Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/officetab?view=common-js-preview). But is there a way to achieve this? Is it possible that the documentation is old?

Comment: Try "TabDraw" as the ID and see if that works.

Comment: @RickKirkham it didnt work :/

Comment: In that case, the Draw tab is not supported for custom controls.